# CIVIRM adding characters to Event name on submission to Paypal, payment received but shows as "pending, incomplete payment"

Tags: civievent, paypal

I'm currently running CIVICRM 4.7.4 with the most current version 7 release of Drupal and am running into an issue with event names when transmitted to Paypal. For example, the event name in CIVICRM is "3V2016 - Module 3 - Instructional Design" but it displays in PayPal as "1679-2049-3V2016 - Modul..." I tried this out by registering myself, and the same thing happened. I can't see any setting in CIVICRM to handle this and it worked fine before upgrading to 4.7.4 (from 4.6.x) so I'm not sure what's happening here.

In addition, for the particular registration in question (the real one) the payment processed through Paypal OK and we received the notification email from Paypal, but nothing from the site, and the registration shows as "Pending, incomplete transaction" Again, this worked fine before the upgrade. I saw somewhere that someone resolved this in a Wordpress installation by making the CIVICRM module's extern folder writable so I've done this (777) rather than (755) so I guess we'll see what happens with that. This is what I found in the log file in the Config and Log directory:
Mar 22 11:44:44  [info] Could not find payment processor for contribution record: 2049

Mar 22 13:45:33  [info] Deprecated: Group='Contribute Preferences'. Name='cvv_backoffice_required'. Defaults should come from metadata

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Chris

Comment: Thanks for this. For the time being I've going back to the previous working release. It would be nice if this inclusion of the ID number could be turned off via some sort of switch, as we have absolutely no use for it here, and in Paypal, the actual title of the course name is cut off, making it harder to match anyway.

Comment: I'm wondering if there have been any further developments with the contact and contribution ID being added to the event name in paypal. Neither I nor the client want this information as it obscures the actual name of the event on the paypal receipt, due to what looks like a character limit. We don't have enough volume to make this a useful "benefit" and we have enough other ways to match the payment to the contributor. Is there a way to turn it off? If not, could one be added? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"1679-2049-3V2016 - Modul..." is the contactID and contribution ID stored within civi respectively, followed by the event title, but concatenated to fit the total length allowed for the Item title.

This seems to be a change in the new version. Quite why this has changed from  just the event title, I'm not sure, but I guess its been added to help reconcile who the contribution is from and what for to make it easier to match up paypal and civi records.

The second issue is different theres a resolution coming out for this for Joomla (see https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18245) - maybe it will fix drupal as well.